# How to use the data from list item as html?

Tags: html

We have a list with Title and Data (multi line field)as columns.

The data field has got html text with all html tags.

When we retrieve and display this text on an page then the html tags can be seen.

We use code like:

divValue.innerHTML=listItems[0]["Data"].ToString();

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
var field = listItem.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Data");     
var htmlValue = field.GetValueAsHtml(listItem[field.Id]);
divValue.innerHTML = htmlValue;
```